# Animating with Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, css, frontend

In this code, I was trying to move the yellow box (the small box) to the right, bottom, left, and top respectively in the red box (the big box) and I have wanted to move the yellow box unendly. I have moved the yellow box to the right and bottom but couldn't move to the left and top. I couldn't understand what the problem is. How should I write this code in Javascript? Could you help me, please? I have used Visual Studio Code.

```js
 window.onload = function(){
                var posX = 0,posY =0, posZ=0;
                var smallbox = document.getElementById("smallbox");
                var time = setInterval(move,10);
    
                function move(){
                    if(posX>=150){
                       if(posY>=150){
                            if(posZ>=150){
                                clearInterval(time);
                            }
                            else{
                                posZ++;
                                smallbox.style.right = posZ + "px";
                            }
                        }
                        else{
                            posY++;
                            smallbox.style.top = posY + "px";
                        }
                    }
                    else{
                        posX = posX+1;
                        smallbox.style.left = posX + "px"; 
                    }
                }
            }
```

```css
        #bigbox{
            height: 200px;
            width: 200px;
            background-color: red;
            position: relative;
        }
        #smallbox{
            height: 50px;
            width: 50px;
            background-color: yellow;
            position: absolute;
        }
```

```html
<div id="bigbox">
   <div id="smallbox">
    
   </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I added a Javascript example to my second answer that I think you will understand.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason that your animation is not working is that CSS alignments for objects must use "top" *or* "bottom" and "left" *or* "right" to align themselves. What you are doing is aligning horizontally using "left" and then trying to align horizontally using "right", or the same thing but around the other way.

What I would instead suggest is using code that essentially reads:

```
if at top-left, move right.
if at top-right, move down.
if at bottom-right, move left.
if at bottom-left, move up.
```

An example of this in action:

```js
window.onload = function() {
  var posX = 0,
    posY = 0,
    boxW = 200,
    boxH = 200,
    smallboxW = 50,
    smallboxH = 50;
  var smallbox = document.getElementById("smallbox");
  var time = setInterval(move, 10);

  function move() {
    if (posY <= 0 && posX < boxW) {
      // go right
      posX++;
      smallbox.style.left = posX + "px";
    }
    if (posX >= boxW - smallboxW && posY < boxH) {
      // go down
      posY++;
      smallbox.style.top = posY + "px";
    }
    if (posY >= boxH - smallboxH && posX > 0) {
      // go left
      posX--;
      smallbox.style.left = posX + "px";
    }
    if (posX <= 0 && posY > 0) {
      // go up
      posY--;
      smallbox.style.top = posY + "px";
    }
  }
}
```

```css
#bigbox {
  height: 200px;
  width: 200px;
  background-color: red;
  position: relative;
}

#smallbox {
  height: 50px;
  width: 50px;
  background-color: yellow;
  position: absolute;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div id="bigbox">
    <div id="smallbox">

    </div>
  </div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 2):

One alternative option is to use the CSS keyframes to animate.

```css
#bigbox {
  height: 200px;
  width: 200px;
  background-color: red;
  position: relative;
}

#smallbox {
  height: 50px;
  width: 50px;
  background-color: yellow;
  position: relative;
  animation: move-around 4s infinite linear;
}

@keyframes move-around {
  0% {
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
    transform: translate(0%, 0%);
  }
  25% {
    left: 100%;
    top: 0;
    transform: translate(-100%, 0%);
  }
  50% {
    left: 100%;
    top: 100%;
    transform: translate(-100%, -100%);
  }
  75% {
    left: 0;
    top: 100%;
    transform: translate(0%, -100%);
  }
  100% {
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
    transform: translate(0%, 0%);
  }
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div id="bigbox">
    <div id="smallbox">

    </div>
  </div>
</body>
```

Comment: Thanks for the comment. It worked but how can i do this without using CSS keyframes? I didn't know the CSS keyframes and I am so newbie in Frontend Development. Also, I want to move yellow box unendly. I think I should try to make an infinite loop or do something with these keyframes. But thanks again for CSS keyframes.

Comment: Edited to make the animation loop.

Answer (score 2):

Instead of managing all calculations yourself, use the power of CSS in javascript with [Element.animate().](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/animate)

This will also allow you to pause and play whenever needed.

```js
const smallbox = document.querySelector('#smallbox');

smallbox.animate([
  // keyframes
  {
    transform: 'translate(150px, 0px)'
  },
  {
    transform: 'translate(150px, 150px)'
  },
  {
    transform: 'translate(0px, 150px)'
  },
  {
    transform: 'translate(0px, 0px)'
  },
  {
    transform: 'translate(150px, 0px)'
  },
], {
  // timing options
  duration: 2000,
  iterations: Infinity
});
```

```css
#bigbox {
  height: 200px;
  width: 200px;
  background-color: red;
  position: relative;
}

#smallbox {
  height: 50px;
  width: 50px;
  background-color: yellow;
  position: absolute;
}
```

```html
<div id="bigbox">
  <div id="smallbox">

  </div>
</div>
```